# If I meet him, I want to tell him

Tags: word-order, conditional-constructions

Can one use

a. If I meet him, I want to tell him how much he has influenced me.

instead of

b. I want to tell him how much he has influenced me if I meet him.

?

Many thanks.

Comment: If you remove _what_ , both sentences are grammatical, but with different emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the 'what' is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you both so very much. The 'what' was a typo. I removed it. My apologies.